# Rstudio Git bash pop-up every time

Tags: r, windows, git, rstudio

I have integrated the git version control to an existing project in Rstudio(Windows). After that for every change I make in the Rmd file, a pop up is coming. I could see that it is a git bash executing on every command I have added in the file. I do not have more details on this.

Comment: having the same error, help is welcome... git is working fine outside of Rstudio, but when in Rstudio Git bash is popping up everytime

Comment: @jebsel sorry, I couldn't help you at this point. I have been provided with a Mac system in which I'm using Rstudio+git without any issues. Still I face the same issue when I work in the windows machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually solved it myself just now with the help of this info:
https://stat545-ubc.github.io/git03_rstudio-meet-git.html

WARNING: On Windows, do NOT use C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd/git.exe. The difference between the good and bad paths is bin vs. cmd.

My Rstudio-version was setting the cmd/git.exe as default.
If you change that to bin/git.exe my problem was solved...